# vuetify expanding table not working as expected with nuxt 3

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vuetify.js, nuxtjs3, vuetifyjs3

Can anyone tell me why my expand includes the whole row please. I am pretty new to this so any advise would be very much appreciated.

I know it works differently in the example on vuetify but i would really like to have total control over each field as well as expand so I can add additional logic on a per item basis.

The other thing it does is only apply my function in the expand, not the main row

Thanks, code below

```
<script setup>

  const headers = [
          {
            title: 'Dessert (100g serving)',
            align: 'start',
            sortable: false,
            key: 'name',
          },
          { title: 'Calories', key: 'calories' },
          { title: 'Fat (g)', key: 'fat' },
          { title: 'Carbs (g)', key: 'carbs' },
          { title: 'Protein (g)', key: 'protein' },
          { title: 'Iron (%)', key: 'iron' },
          { title: '', key: 'data-table-expand'},
        ]
    
          const desserts = [
          {
            name: 'Frozen Yogurt',
            calories: 59,
            fat: 6.0,
            carbs: 24,
            protein: 4.0,
            iron: 1,
          },
          {
            name: 'Ice cream sandwich',
            calories: 27,
            fat: 9.0,
            carbs: 37,
            protein: 4.3,
            iron: 1,
          },
          {
            ...
          },
   
          
        ]

      const expanded = []
      const getColor = (calories) => {
        if (calories > 100) return 'red'
        else if (calories > 50) return 'orange'
        else return 'green'
      }

</script>

<template>
    <div>

      <v-main style="height: 88vh">
        <v-sheet class="ml-4 mt-2">
    
        <h1 class="ml-3 mt-3">Title</h1>

        <v-data-table
            :headers="headers"
            :items="desserts"
            :sort-by="[{ key: 'calories', order: 'asc' }]"
            v-model="expanded"
            item-value="name"
            show-expand
        >

            <template v-slot:top>
                <v-toolbar flat>
                    <v-toolbar-title>Expandable Table</v-toolbar-title>
                </v-toolbar>
            </template>

            <template v-slot:expanded-row="{ columns, item }" >
            <tr>
                <td>{{ item.name }}</td>
                <td><v-chip :color="getColor(item.calories)">{{ item.calories }}</v-chip></td>
                <td>{{ item.fat }}</td>
                <td>{{ item.carbs }}</td>
                <td>{{ item.protein }}</td>
                <td>{{ item.iron }}</td>

                <template>
                <tr>
                    <td :colspan="columns.length">
                        More info about {{ item.name }}
                    </td>
                </tr>
                </template>
            </tr>
            </template>
        </v-data-table>
   
    </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Can you explain what you mean it's not working as expected?  What is the expectation? What does "total control" entail? Vuetify provides functionality for a row to expand, and your row expands.  What is actually wrong with it? Also, your function only works on the expanded row because you've placed it in the `expanded-row` slot.  The "main row" would be the `item` slot.  If you're new to Vue I'd recommend becoming familiar with [slots documentation](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/slots.html), it may help clear up some confusion.

Comment: Thank you... can anyone tell me why in my item vslot (Which I ve added following the help above from yoduh) the following doesnt work <td> <button @click="item.expanded = !item.expanded">test</button></td>

Comment: You can use the dynamic slots ```header.<key>``` to customize only certain columns. ```<key>``` corresponds to the key property in the items found in the headers prop => https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables/basics/#header-slot